# "START TRANSACTION" in MySQL causing connection timeout

Tags: mysql

I have one functionality called `clone` in which i have to copy millions of records from one project to another project(multiple tables). For this I am using store procedure of `MySQL`.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `clone_new`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `clone_new`(
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    SHOW ERRORS;
  ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO XXX SELECT * FROM XXXX ....
.....
.....

COMMIT;
    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Problem here is without `START TRANSACTION;` insertion happening very slow, but due to `START TRANSACTION;` `MySQL` put a lock on that table until that transaction got finish. Which is causing `Connection Timeout` for other clients.

`START TRANSACTION;` is required to do rollback if any error occur.

What can i do to get performance without affecting other users?

**NOTE:**  WE are using `innodb` table.

Comment: What isolation level are you using?. Check `SELECT @@GLOBAL.\`tx_isolation\`, @@SESSION.\`tx_isolation\`;`. See [14.5.2.1 Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html).

Comment: In both i have REPEATABLE-READ

Comment: You can change isolation level in the stored procedure (per session), however, you must evaluate the impact and effects that this change can generate throughout the system.

Comment: Which should I try ?

Comment: I change the isolation level that solve my issue. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue by changing `Isolation Level` from `REPEATABLE READ` to `READ COMMITTED`.

I found this documentation.

> In `REPEATABLE READ` every lock acquired during a transaction is held
>   for the duration of the transaction.
>
> In `READ COMMITTED` the locks that did not match the scan are released
>   after the `STATEMENT` completes.